# Syntax for sumif from different Excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do you do sumifs in Excel across different spreadsheet files ?

I know how to do a sumifs across different tabs within a spreadsheet  (using sumproduct(sumifs(indirect etc etc) but can't seem to get it to work across seperate spreadsheets ??

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to find out:

Requirement, both workbooks:
They must have been SAVED to disk (At least so in LibreOffice).

NOTE: I believe; To have this kind of formula "work" you must have both workbooks open.

- Select a cell in the worksheet where you wish to have your formula.
- Type `=` to start formula entry.
- Now create your formula, at the point where you want your external worksheet reference, just skip over (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> is easiest!) to the second workbook and click on the cell you wish to reference.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> again is the easy way to get back.
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when done, as normal.

At this point you will see the correct syntax for the reference, in your formula.

Comment: that does not seem to work as you cannot define a range across different workbooks (at least I have not figured out how to)

Comment: Well, that was strange; I can no longer make it work - it SHOULD work though ...> https://help.libreoffice.org/3.3/Calc/Referencing_a_Cell_in_Another_Document and i DID try it as I wrote the above, and a single cell reference was OK